# How can I give a default boundingBox to selectROI in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

when using `cv2.selectROI` opencv provides me with a GUI to select a bounding box. What I'm looking for, is to provide a default bounding box without the need for user intecraction, which I will get using contours.

Is there any way for me to do this on opencv

Comment: "provide a default bounding box" to what? Just use the rectangle definition obtained "using contours" instead of the one returned by `selectROI`. I'm honestly not sure what you're actually asking for...

Answer (score 0):

To expand the comment by @Dan Masek

You can use boundingRect to get the x/y location and the width and height of a box encompassing the contour like this:

`x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)`

These are also the values returned by selectROI(), so you can use boundingRect instead.

[Example showing boudingRect](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#bounding-rectangle)